# iOS ZBAR instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier after reader didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo

Tags: ios, objective-c, zbar-sdk, zbar

Im running a function under didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo but how can i render another viewController after the function finish

```
- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController*) reader
 didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary*) info
{
    id<NSFastEnumeration> results =[info objectForKey: ZBarReaderControllerResults];

    NSString *qr;
    for (ZBarSymbol *symbol in results) {
        NSLog(@"Resultado: %@", symbol.data);
        qr = symbol.data;
    }

    [reader dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        [self procesarCheckInConQR:qr];
    }];

}
```

i tried adding

```
UIViewController *newTopViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"rootCarta"];
[reader presentViewController:newTopViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

after

```
[reader dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        [self procesarCheckInConQR:qr];
    }];
```

and the view is rendered, but data from [self procesarCheckInConQR:qr]; isnt ready yet

**Update:**
Instead of dismiss i present the new view controller, but i still dont have data from
procesarCheckInConQR:qr

```
UIViewController *newTopViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"rootCarta"];
[reader presentViewController:newTopViewController animated:YES completion:^{
    [self procesarCheckInConQR:qr];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your call inside the block after `[self procesarCheckInConQR:qr]`

Comment: Warning: Attempt to present <UINavigationController: 0x145eca80> on <ZBarReaderViewController: 0x146d10c0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Comment: @jtomasrl You can't present a new controller from the just dismissed image picker.

Comment: so instead dismissing the image picker i render the view and attach the function to the completion option. But the view is rendered before i can get the data from the function inside completion